# XML not being deserialized into object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I posted a [question very similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73814751/deserializing-xml-to-class-some-elements-not-not-pulling-through?noredirect=1#comment130340289_73814751) with a different XML/object model and it was resolved by suggestions to add missing `{set; }` on my properties of the class. While that worked there, with the class I'm trying to get to deserialize a different XML file, the `{set; }` are not missing.

The **XML** that I'm currently trying to deserialize looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <BillOfMaterials xmlns='http://www.manh.com/ILSNET/Interface' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.manh.com/ILSNET/Interface'>
        <BillOfMaterial>
            <Active>Y</Active>
            <Company>XYZ</Company>
            <InterfaceEntity>
                <Action>NEW</Action>
            </InterfaceEntity>
            <Item>PM6000035437</Item>
            <QtyUm>EA</QtyUm>
            <RevisionNum>1</RevisionNum>
            <BillOfMaterialDetails>
                <BillOfMaterialDetail>
                    <BuildLevel>1</BuildLevel>
                    <BuildSequence>1</BuildSequence>
                    <Company>XYZ</Company>
                    <InterfaceEntity>
                        <Action>NEW</Action>
                    </InterfaceEntity>
                    <Item>DP000351</Item>
                    <QtyNeededPerItem>3.0</QtyNeededPerItem>
                </BillOfMaterialDetail>
                <BillOfMaterialDetail>
                    <BuildLevel>1</BuildLevel>
                    <BuildSequence>2</BuildSequence>
                    <Company>XYZ</Company>
                    <InterfaceEntity>
                        <Action>NEW</Action>
                    </InterfaceEntity>
                    <Item>DP000354</Item>
                    <QtyNeededPerItem>1.0</QtyNeededPerItem>
                </BillOfMaterialDetail>
     </BillOfMaterial>
</BillOfMaterials>
```

My first class is the parent **BillOfMaterial class**, below:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "BillOfMaterials", Namespace = "http://www.manh.com/ILSNET/Interface")]
public class BOMList
{
    [XmlElement("BillOfMaterial")]
    public BOM[] BOMs { get; set; }
}

public class BOM
{
    [XmlElement("BillOfMaterialDetails")]
    public BOMDetail[] Details { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Active")]
    public string ActiveFlag { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("QtyUm")]
    public string QtyUOM { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("RevisionNum")]
    public string RevisionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the **BOMDetail class** which the BOM contains a collection of is below:

```
public class BOMDetail
{
    [XmlElement]
    public int BuildLevel { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public int BuildSequence { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QtyNeededPerItem")]
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is that when testing this, the BOM parent object is correctly pulling data from the XML file, but the BOMDetails collection inside of it is null, when it should (in this example) contain two BOMDetail elements.

My code that does the deserialization is below:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BOMList));

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    this.CreatedObjects = (BOMList)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: You show no actual code to read the xml. Have you used try / catch to establish the error?

Comment: hi @AndrewTruckle, sorry, I spaced on including that. I added it now. Re. the error: there is no error/exception occurring, it just does not pull the XML data into the object.

Comment: I see it knows about the main collection element but not that each child has its own node. Maybe you need to tell it a little more about the array structure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

Comment: Specifically I'm thinking that your class `BOMDetail` needs one of the decorators in that link I posted so it knows it goes with its own node?

Comment: The xml you paste here is not correct, you need close tag `</BillOfMaterialDetails>`

Comment: In Visual Studio you can paste a XML class in a special way to extract the required classes. Why not try that and compare the results between the boilerplate code it generates and your own classes?

Comment: Your `<BillOfMaterialDetails>` list has an outer container element so replace `[XmlElement("BillOfMaterial")] public BOMDetail[] Details { get; set; }` with `[XmlArray("BillOfMaterialDetails"), XmlArrayItem("BillOfMaterialDetail")] public BOMDetail[] Details { get; set; }` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086668/3744182) by [Brian Ensink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254/brian-ensink) to [XmlSerializer.Deserialize on a List<> item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2086635/3744182).  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/MJPuov

Comment: Everything is working after I added missing tag.  I used following code : XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BOMList));
            BOMList bomList = (BOMList)serializer.Deserialize(reader); Only issue I'm seeing is you are missing a class for InterfaceEntity

Comment: @AvivHalevy thanks for pointing that out. The XML file itself was fine, that was a mistake I made when stripping text and posting it into this question.

Comment: @dbc Thank you so much! That resolved it. While my question was sort of specific to my business requirements... I don't know if you want to add an answer for me to mark as an answer, or if we just allow the question that was already answered to be the answer going forward and just let this post "die". Either way, thanks very much for your help.